# How to Inject Hibernate Session into a Servlet inside Tapestry?

Tags: tapestry

I have a HttpServlet inside tapestry project. But I think it is not recognized as a part of IoC. So when I do an `@inject` it does not work. It ends up throwing a null pointer exception. Any suggestion about how to inject the same hibernate session.

Comment: Maybe following thread can help you? http://tapestry.1045711.n5.nabble.com/How-to-get-a-service-whithout-using-Inject-td5713412.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the servlet doPost() method I did the following.

```
Registry registry = (Registry)
getServletContext().getAttribute(TapestryFilter.REGISTRY_CONTEXT_NAME);         
hbSession = registry.getService(Session.class);
```